# React Native Component NOT re-rendering

Tags: react-native

for some reason the component is not Re-Rendering on the setDependent, i have added the setPerson and the console does log the item without that one deleted, but is not updating the component. please see code below, as of right now is loading with no problem from the server but at the moment of deletion it does send the command to delete but the list does not get re-render, the "person" still listed on the FlatList

```
const RemoveDependent = ({ onPress }) =>
(
    <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={onPress}>
        <View style={{
            backgroundColor: colors.dangerLight,
            //height: 70,
            width: 70,
            //borderRadius: 35,
            right:-5,
            justifyContent: 'center',
            alignItems: 'center'
        }}>
            <MaterialCommunityIcons name="trash-can" size={30} style={{ color: colors.white }} />
        </View>
    </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
)



function FamilyScreen(props) {
    const [person, setDependent] = useState(dependents);
    const handleRemove = onDependent => {
        console.log(person.filter(d => d.id !== onDependent.id));
        setDependent(person.filter((d) => d.id !== onDependent.id));
    }
    return (
        <View style={{ backgroundColor: colors.white, flex: 1 }}>
            <Image
                source={require('../assets/familyBg.jpeg')}
                style={styles.image}
                resizeMode="cover"
            />
            <View style={styles.details}>
                <RevText style={styles.title}>Family Plan</RevText>
                <RevText style={styles.description}>Description here</RevText>
            </View>
            <FlatList
                data={dependents}
                keyExtractor={personal => personal.id.toString()}
                renderItem={({ item }) => (
                    <ListItem
                        onPress={() => handleRemove(item) }
                        title={item.name}
                        subTitle={item.type}
                        image={item.image}
                        renderRightActions={() => (<RemoveDependent onPress={() => handleRemove(item)} />) }
                        ItemSeparatorComponent={() => (<View style={{ width: '96%', left: 5, borderBottomColor: 'red', borderBottomWidth: 1 }} />)}
                    />
                )}
            />
        </View>
    );
}




Object {
      "id": 1014,//REMOVED ID WHEN CLICKED
      "image": 19,
      "name": "Person 1",
      "type": "Child",
    }
    Array [ //NEW ARRAY
      Object {
        "id": 1015,
        "image": 19,
        "name": "PERSON 2",
        "type": "Child",
      },
      Object {
        "id": 1016,
        "image": 19,
        "name": "PERSON 3",
        "type": "Child",
      },
      Object {
        "id": 1017,
        "image": 19,
        "name": "PERSON 4",
        "type": "Child",
      },
    ]
```

Comment: Please include a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible Code Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in your question. Images of code are not searchable and are more difficult to read. Your flatlist isn't rendering your state, but rather what your state was initialized to, i.e. `dependent` vs `dependents`. Voting to close as "Unreproducible or caused by typo".

Comment: I have updated and added the code, but there was no typo i did change some of the code so the difference can be noticed, the object gets removed from the Array but is not re-rendering

Comment: I guess the "typo" still exists. `person` is your state but you still pass `dependents` to the `FlatList`. What is `dependents`?

Comment: Man you saved me !! sorry is because the "dependents" is the actual data coming from the Server i forgot to change it when i take it from Server and pass it for State ... you got it my bad! ... Thanks again... is working now!

Answer (score 0):

The main problem with this code is that your are altering a state object directly. You should treat all state objects as if they are immutable.

change

```
setDependent(person.filter((d) => d.id !== onDependent.id));
```

with

```
setDependent([...person.filter((d) => d.id != onDependent.id)]);
```

Comment: nah, code was right problem was rendering back on set list. thanks tho !